# Python: data on many people - how to structure?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm currently working on a project where I extract data about people from a government website. I've extracted the data, but now I need to store it. I'm not an advanced programming, so I was hoping people here can give me advice.

For each person I have the following information:
Name, current (main) function/job (can be more than 1), additional function(s), previous jobs.

Putting lists inside lists here is giving me trouble, so a link to a picture of the outline instead:

[image]

I was thinking about using a class, to easily generate the info tree for each person. I'd like to put the instances of the class in an array, so that I can count how many people there are in my array. I'd also like to know how many main jobs someone has, how many side jobs and do some comparisons with time (e.g. how many side jobs did someone have before they started their main job).

The searchable part is what has me stuck. I don't know whether it's best to use classes, or dictionaries, or perhaps dictionaries with instances of classes inside them.

What would the best way to approach this be?

Comment: Are you using a database to store data?

Comment: No, I unfortunately don't know things like SQL. It's on my longer-term wishlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping the Person and Job classes is a good start. The questions you are asking, though, are well answered by a Relational Database, as your data seems to fit well in those type of databases.

You'd have a Jobs table and a Persons table, where a person may have multiple jobs (you'd need a reference such as `person_id` in the Jobs table). What isn't so clear to me is if there are sufficient differences between Jobs, Side Jobs and Previous Jobs to justify multiple tables, maybe a type column is sufficient to differentiate.

As you seem to be in a hurry, I'd really recommend checking out [dataset](http://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

```
import dataset

db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///:memory:')
persons_table = db['persons']
persons_table.insert(dict(name='Jolien'))

jobs_table = db['jobs']
jobs_table.insert(dict(place='Mall', start_date=2012, type=1, salary=20000, person_id=1))
```

Then you can ask questions using raw SQL:

```
res = db.query('SELECT count(*) FROM jobs WHERE person_id = 1 AND type = 2')
```

Comment: Great, if this answers your question fully, please consider accepting my answer.